# Eliminando caracteres extras usando scanf

Tags: c

Olá, amigos!

Estou criando um programa que lê dados separados por ponto e vírgula, os checa e retorna uma lista com possíveis erros. (exemplo: o usuário entra CNPJ,razão social, UF da seguinte forma: 12345678901234;empresa x;SP). Estou fazendo assim pois o próximo passo é pegar um arquivo .txt pronto com milhares de empresas nessa formatação e usá-la no programa.

O problema é que, como os dados como CNPJ e UF têm números específicos de caracteres a serem inseridos (14 e 2), devo colocar no scanf para as strings receberem valores específicos do cnpj e do UF.
Isto eu consigo fazer sem problemas, inclusive a parte de ler os dados até o ponto e vírgula. O que acontece é que, se o usuário digita caracteres extras em CNPJ (15 caracteres, por exemplo), o buffer do teclado carrega o caracter extra para os próximos dados, comprometendo todas as informações seguintes. Como faço para que isto não ocorra?
Segue abaixo o trecho a que me refiro:

```
scanf( "%14[^;];%40[^;];%8[^;];%2[^;\r\n]%*[;\r\n]",
          cnpj,
          razao_social,
          data_de_fundacao,
          uf );
          validaCNPJ(cnpj);
    if (validaCNPJ(cnpj) == 0){
        cnpjErr = cnpjErr + 1;
        }

    contador_linhas++;

    printf( "\n[%4d][%-14s][%-40s][%-8s][%-2s]",
            contador_linhas,
            cnpj,
            razao_social,
            data_de_fundacao,
            uf );
```

Comment: Você já chegou a dar uma olhada na função fflush?

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução bastante simples é consumir o fim da linha após cada leitura. Remova `%*[;\r\n]` do seu `scanf`. Então após cada leitura, seja ela bem sucedida ou não, execute um `fgets` com um buffer de tamanho razoável. Ele vai ler a linha toda e posicionar a próxima leitura no início da próxima linha.

Devo alertar, no entanto, que uma forma provavelmente melhor de fazer isso seria lendo a linha inteira e depois processando com `strtok`, quebrando nos pontos e vírgula. Assim não terá que lidar com a string de formato do `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Usa o retorno do `scanf()`

```
if (scanf("%14[^;];%40[^;];%8[^;];%2[^;\r\n]%*[;\r\n]",
          cnpj,
          razao_social,
          data_de_fundacao,
          uf) != 4) /* erro */;
```